# How can I show only a certain number of posts in a query?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to query for the 3 most recent posts in the home page of my website powered by Wordpress:

```
    wp_reset_postdata();
    wp_reset_query();
    query_posts('showposts=3');
    rewind_posts();
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        // do stuff.
        the_title();
    endwhile;
```

However, 7 posts are being displayed. Furthermore, not all of these 7 posts are the latest posts. Above this query, there are other queries.

As you see, I have tried reseting the post data and the query data to no avail. What other factors could affect the posts retrieved?

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/36453/how-to-display-last-3-posts-recent-posts-in-a-static-page

Comment: Thanks, but specifying `posts_per_page=3` doesn't seem to do it either...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that you don't put that code in another `have_posts` loop.
This should work:

```
query_posts( array( 'posts_per_page' => 3, 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC' ) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        // do stuff.
        the_title();
    endwhile;
```